# Rails 3 and iOS Architecture Review

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ios, authentication, architecture

My goal is to build a standalone RESTful Rails 3 service that communicates with a Rails 3 web application via ActiveResource JSON and an iPhone application via iOS 5 native JSON.  I have each running so that a single table of data is being exposed in the service app and that can be called and rendered via both a Rails app and the iPhone app.

My question is around authentication and something that can be reusable for both the web application and the iPhone app or in the future an Android app.

From the research I have done on this site, it seems HTTP Basic would work for both, however I would be unable to properly logout a user on the web side like sessions or cookies could and I have the browser login form to deal with.  If I use sessions, how would that translate to setting up authentication on the iOS side of things?

This project is a code learning exercise, so I am hoping for implementation or architectural guidance rather than simply implementing Devise or Authlogic, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're conflating at least two problems.

The first issue is authentication: you need to determine if the user is who they say they are.  For authentication, you can do basic auth.  You could also use client certs, though that's probably not what you're looking for.

The second thing is session management:  First, you can do basic auth on each page request and store the session state in the database, but you're right about not being able to log the user out, as the browser will cache the credentials.

You may want to consider a login page that requires basic auth and shoots back a cookie to do session management.  All other pages don't require basic auth, but give a 401 unauthorized if the cookie isn're present.  Or you could redirect.  The iOS client code will have to know to call the login page first to get the cookie and then use it after that.  Logging out is deleting the cookie.. hrmm, but the browser will still cache the basic auth credentials.

I'm thinking the only way you're going to get what you want is to have a form-based auth for your web users (to allow them to log out and log in as someone else), and a basic-auth based system for iOS users.  As a result of both authentication mechanisms, return a cookie that has to be used for all other pages.

Comment: Thanks Xaxxon.  When you say "You may want to consider a login page that requires basic auth", do you mean to use the built in browser login form when doing HTTP Basic or is there a way to create a custom login form, but pass the values in the header thereby never seeing the browser login form?

Comment: have two ways to get the ticket.  One way that uses basic auth for your iOS client to get their session cookie and another page that uses form auth that your traditional web users will use to get their session cookie.